How does an "Attach to Process" action for remote process decide whether or not to do the actual attaching?
I'm working on a C# application, installed on a remote computer. On that remote computer, msvsmon.exe is running.
When I compile my sources and install the latest build, I am able to perform an "Attach to Process".
However, there are quite some cases where the "Attach to Process" does not work, especially when different people are "playing" with GIT and when different people try to attach to a process, built by another colleague.
We are two colleagues, both working on a "Debug" build of the application, both have "Any CPU" as a solution platform.
My question is: what does Visual Studio check in order to decide whether or not to actual perform an "Attach to process"? (Source code, how does Visual Studio know about that? Debugging symbols (*.pdb files), how ...? Other? ...)
The errormessage we get is "No Symbols have been loaded for this document", and we have the habit of compiling the application on our own PC and copy both the binaries and the "*.pdb" files to the customer system.

Can you be a bit more specific on what you mean by "Attach to Process doesn't work"? What exactly happens if you execute the command?

I mean that breakpoints get disabled.

For breakpoints getting disabled,  did you check the doc  to troubleshoot your breakpoints?

@DouXu-MSFT: I have edited my question, showing the error message.

It sounds like what you need is source indexing, which is the process wherein the PDBs contain information about how to get the right source file from your source control system. It's been a number of years since I last tried to do this and it looks like this is still a painful process. There is support for symbols for nuget which looks a bit easier to do these days except you wouldn't generally be creating a nuget package for the application itself.

For debugging to work correctly, the files in the output folder (dlls, exes and pdbs) must match exactly the source files they where generated with. Thus only the user that generated the output is able to debug it, unless you use source indexing together with a CI pipeline. But that doesn't help that much, since normally developers want to be able to test their local changes before CI runs.
Therefore, if remote debugging is necessary, only one user should do so at a time. And they should make sure they copy their bin folders to the remote machine before they start working. A good solution is to use something like winscp to sync the local bin directory with the remote machine while working. That way, after any change-and-rebuild, the remote automatically gets the fixed code.
